# How do I activate the click event for a button on Android?

Tags: java, android

How do I activate the click event for a button on Android?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a very very simple question. You should read Android API document first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You push the button (please elaborate if that wasn't the answer you were looking for)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if you want to "click" the button via java or listen for the click event.

The listening is descirbed correctly by Graham

To automaticly click the Button you could call

```
Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

`b.performClick();`

Answer (score 5):

In your layout file, include this in the button definition:

```
android:onClick="myClickHandler"
```

In your activity code, implement the handler:

```
void myClickHandler(View view) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would read through this document. It contains all you need and more:

http://d.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope It will helpful for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

   @Override
   public void OnClick(View view) {
    //code
   }

}
```

Comment: Please note that your activity has to implement onClickListener